# is it possible to access cross site POST method in Extjs4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

i try with this code it is  possible to access get method but i wont to access post method so how can i do that

```
Ext.define('User', {

     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     fields: ['id', 'name', 'email']
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User',
    restful:true,   
        proxy: {
       type: 'jsonp',
       url: 'http://localhost:8080/testapp/userreg',
       callbackKey: 'Callback'
    },

        headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json'    
        }
    });

    store.load();
```

is there any way to post cross site data in extjs4

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that you want to post data cross-domain...no, you can't. I know that with the new Javascript Api's ([XMLHttpRequest2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/)) it can be done but I don't know if that is an option for you right now.

Comment: I would only add that using the jsonp proxy is the appropriate way to send data to a cross-domain server, but as the asker suggested it uses script tags, and GET as opposed to POST.

Answer (score 0):

try use jquery

```
    $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url : urlServer+'/ws/Login/',
                            xhrFields: {
                                withCredentials: true
                            },
                            scope: this, 
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data:values,
                            timeout: 10000,
                            success: function(result, request) {
```